# Error loading data from wcf service only when site is published

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm posting a site with reference to a wcf service, but when it is published returns an error message, why only when it's published?

Comment: We need far more details. My guess: the URL for your service is incorrect.

Comment: The remote name could not be resolved: 'masaval-001-site1.smarterasp.net'  [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://masaval-001-site1.smarterasp.net/ServicioMasAval.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]